# disable a button from datagrid view based on a column in datagrid c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

How do I disable a button in `wpf`?

I have a column named `availability` which should conatin the values `available` or `unavailable`, 
and I want to disable the button if the value is `unavailable`:

```
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button x:Name="deployBtn" Click="deployBtn_Click" Height="25" Width="45" Background="#FF43B46C"  Margin="0 -3 0 0">
                                        <Button.ToolTip>
                                            <ToolTip>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Deploy</TextBlock>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </ToolTip>
                                        </Button.ToolTip>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="PackageUp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="35" Margin="-12 0 0 0"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Tried setting the IsEnabled property on the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using DataTemplate Triggers and set needed property inside it. For example, if Availability is a property in DataContext of DataTemplateColumn, it will look nearly like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
     <Button x:Name="deployBtn" Click="deployBtn_Click" Height="25" Width="45" Background="#FF43B46C"  Margin="0 -3 0 0">
     //...your code
     </Button>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers> 
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.Availability RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataTemplateColumn}}" Value="Unavailable">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" TargetName="deployBtn" Value="False"/>
     </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
  </DataTemplate>
```